# Проблема с "Дизайнером" в phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, связи, таблицы, дизайнер

На хостинге есть 3 таблицы (InnoDB) со связями. У каждой  есть свой первичный ключ. При добавлении ограничения везде выбирал ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE. Всё отлично работает, но в дизайнере связи не отображаются и появляется данное окно (скрин). Даже перемещать таблицы нельзя.

Причём окно Удалить связь накладывается на Создать связь.

Версия phpMyAdmin: 4.4.15.10

Причём точно так же на локалке с последней версией phpMyAdmin.
В чём может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: upd: на сайте demo.phpmyadmin.net залил свою бд. Там Дизайнер прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

скачай последнюю версию phpmyadmin и распакуй в папку, где лежит у тебя phpmyadmin (на локальном сервере помогло)